# security:http and properties (Spring Security)

Tags: java, properties, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.0.6. for modularity reasons, I would like to use properties in the security:http context.

```
<security:http>
  ...
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/path/to/my/url/*" access="${token}" />
  ...
</security:http>
```

Is that possible ?
If not, if there any workaround that could be used to obtain the same behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).